# Hibernate Envers 4 not auditing entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers 4.1.0 + Spring 3.1.0 on my application running on Wildfly 9.0.2. Whenever I insert or update a entity it persists the entity just fine but Envers does not persist a new rev on my AUD tables.

I'm searching for quiet a while for a answer but still hasn't found it.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Implement manually listeners on my `context.xml`. Later it came to my knowledge that starting from Envers 4 the listeners would be created dynamically, so no need to implement it on `context.xml`.
2. Change Envers version. This could work, I actually don't know because the application won't start with a newer Envers version and the client is not willing to pay for a Framework update refactoring.

Here is what I know:

1. As I already said, the entity are fine, Hibernate does persists it when I create a new one or update a existing one.
2. I was debugging some Envers classes like `EnversIntegrator`, `EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl` and `EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl` and they are indeed been added to the listeners and last 2 classes are creating the `AuditWorkUnit` fine. I couldn't find exactly where the transaction happens tho.

Here are some additional information:

One of my entities:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@AuditTable(value = "AUTUADO_AUD", schema = "SISTAC")
@Table(name = "AUTUADO", schema = "SISTAC")
public class Autuado extends BaseEntity<Integer> {

    public Autuado(Integer idAutuado) {
    this.id = idAutuado;
    }

    public Autuado() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "SISTAC.SEQ_AUTUADO", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "SEQ_AUTUADO")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NOM_AUTUADO")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "NOM_APELIDO_AUTUADO")
    private String apelido;

    @Column(name = "NOM_MAE_AUTUADO")
    private String mae;

    @Column(name = "NOM_PAI_AUTUADO")
    private String pai;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DAT_NASCIMENTO_AUTUADO")
    private Date datNascimento;

    @Column(name = "TIP_SEXO")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SexoEnum sexo;

    @Column(name = "NOM_PAIS_NACIONALIDADE")
    private String nacionalidade;

    @Column(name = "NOM_CIDADE_NATURALIDADE")
    private String naturalidade;

    @Column(name = "SIG_UF_NATURALIDADE")
    private String ufNaturalidade;

    @Column(name = "NOM_LOGRADOURO_ENDERECO")
    private String endereco;

    @Column(name = "NOM_BAIRRO_ENDERECO")
    private String bairro;

    @Column(name = "DSC_COMPLEMENTO_ENDERECO")
    private String complEndereco;

    @Column(name = "NOM_CIDADE_ENDERECO")
    private String cidadeEndereco;

    @Column(name = "SIG_UF_ENDERECO")
    private String ufEndereco;

    @Column(name = "NUM_TELEFONE_AUTUADO")
    private String telefone;

    @Column(name = "FLG_ESTUDANTE")
    private String estuda;

    @Column(name = "FLG_INDIGENA")
    private String indigena;

    @Column(name = "FLG_EMPREGO_FORMAL")
    private String empregoFormal;

    @Column(name = "FLG_GRAVIDA")
    private String gestante;

    @Column(name = "FLG_POSSUI_DEPENDENTE")
    private String dependentes;

    @Column(name = "FLG_DOENCA_GRAVE")
    private String doenca;

    @Column(name = "FLG_PORTADOR_DEFICIENCIA")
    private String deficiente;

    @Column(name = "FLG_DEPENDENTE_QUIMICO")
    private String depQuimico;

    @Column(name = "FLG_USA_MEDICAMENTO")
    private String usaMedicamento;

    @Column(name = "FLG_ANTECEDENTE_CRIMINAL")
    private String antCriminal;

    @Column(name = "USU_INCLUSAO")
    private String usuInclusao;

    @Column(name = "QTD_FILHO_MENOR_6_ANOS")
    private Integer qtdDepMenor;

    @Column(name = "QTD_FILHO_PORTADOR_DEFICIENCIA")
    private Integer qtdDepDeficiente;

    @Column(name = "QTD_OUTROS_DEPENDENTES")
    private Integer qtdDepOutros;

    @Column(name = "DSC_IDIOMA_AUTUADO")
    private String idiomaAutuado;

    @Column(name = "DSC_MEDICAMENTO")
    private String medicamento;

    @Column(name = "DSC_TATUAGEM")
    private String tatuagem;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DAT_INCLUSAO")
    private Date datInclusao;

    @Column(name = "USU_ALTERACAO")
    private String usuAlteracao;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DAT_ALTERACAO")
    private Date datAlteracao;

    @Column(name = "FLG_ATIVO")
    private String flgAtivo;

    @Column(name="NUM_CELULAR_AUTUADO")
    private String celular;

    @Column(name="NOM_CONTATO_AUTUADO")
    private String contatoReferencia;

    @Column(name="NUM_CONTATO_AUTUADO")
    private String telefoneReferencia;

    @Column(name="FLG_EMPREGO_INFORMAL")
    private String empregoInFormal;

    @Column(name="FLG_LGBTI")
    private String flgLgbt;

    //    -------------------- MANY TO ONE --------------------

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_RACA_COR")
    private RacaCor cor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_ESTADO_CIVIL")
    private EstadoCivil estadoCivil;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_ESCOLARIDADE")
    private Escolaridade escolaridade;

    //    -------------------- ONE TO MANY --------------------

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autuado")
    private Collection<Audiencia> audiencias;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autuado", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<DoencaAutuado> listDoencas;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autuado", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<AntecedenteCriminal> listAntecCriminal;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autuado", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<DocumentoAutuado> documentos;

    //    -------------------- MANY TO MANY --------------------

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "SISTAC.DEFICIENCIA_AUTUADO", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_AUTUADO") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_TIPO_DEFICIENCIA") })
    private Collection<Deficiencia> listDeficiencias;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "SISTAC.DEPENDENCIA_QUIMICA_AUTUADO", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_AUTUADO") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_TIPO_SUBSTANCIA_QUIMICA") })
    private Collection<SubstanciaQuimica> dependenciasQuimicas;
}
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project-sistac-1</groupId>
    <artifactId>sistac</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.2.1</version>
    <name>sistac Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion> 
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.dom4j.dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>20041127.091804</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.six2six</groupId>
            <artifactId>fixture-factory</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>sistac</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

My `applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName" default-lazy-init="true">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.jus.cnj" />    

    <!-- Configuração para executar no ambiente de homologação e produção -->
    <bean id="dataSourceMysql" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" autowire-candidate="default">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/sistacMySql"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceOracle" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/sistacOracle"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactoryMysql" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" autowire-candidate="default">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMysql" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.jus.cnj.corporativo.bean" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactoryOracle" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" autowire-candidate="false">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceOracle" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.jus.cnj.sistac.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryMysql" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagerOracle" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryOracle" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="corporativoPerfilBC" class="br.jus.cnj.corporativo.business.CorporativoPerfilBC" />
    <bean id="corporativoSistemaBC" class="br.jus.cnj.corporativo.business.CorporativoSistemaBC" />
    <bean id="corporativoOrgaoBC" class="br.jus.cnj.corporativo.business.CorporativoOrgaoBC" />

</beans>
```

The class I used to generate the DDL's for the AUD tables.

```
public class HibernateEnversDDLGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HibernateEnversDDLGenerator generator = new HibernateEnversDDLGenerator();
        generator.createSchema(Dialect.ORACLE, "br.jus.cnj.sistac.entity");
    }
    enum Dialect {
        MYSQL("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"),
        ORACLE("org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"),
        SYBASE("org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseAnywhereDialect");

        private String className;

        Dialect(String className) {
            this.className = className;
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return className;
        }
    }

    private void createSchema(Dialect dialect, String entitiesPackage) {
        Reflections ref = new Reflections(entitiesPackage);
        Set<Class<?>> auditedClasses = ref.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Audited.class);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, dialect.getClassName());
        for (Class<?> entityClass : auditedClasses) {
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(entityClass);
        }
        configuration.buildMappings();
        AuditConfiguration.getFor(configuration);

        SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport(configuration);
        schemaExport.setDelimiter(";");
        schemaExport.setOutputFile(String.format("%s_%s.%s ", "ddl_audit", dialect.name().toLowerCase(), "sql"));
        boolean consolePrint = true;
        boolean exportInDatabase = false;
        schemaExport.create(consolePrint, exportInDatabase);
    }
}
```

My `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SISTAC</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilterOracle</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactoryOracle</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilterMySQL</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
      <param-value>sessionFactoryMysql</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
        </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
      <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilterOracle</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilterMySQL</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>principal.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you see the `AuditWorkUnit` objects being created then that does imply the listeners are firing; however if those work units are never persisted to the database that typically means the `before-transaction-completion` callback did not fire or ran into some error (altho the latter should cause the transaction to rollback).  Could you update your post to include how you scope your transactions?  Are you using anything such as `OpenSessionInViewFilter` in your spring-app?

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed using OpenSessionInViewFilter on my app. I updated with my `web.xml`.

Comment: Even with the `OpenSessionInView` filter being applied, the updates should still happen to the envers tables.  The difference is those updates after **after** your view has been rendered and not prior.  This is because the filter keeps the session **and** transaction active until the view is rendered at which point is when the transaction gets committed & those Envers callbacks fire.